# dokku sass error on digital ocean

Tags: node.js, sass, sails.js, digital-ocean, dokku

I have a standard DO dokku image that I am using to host a Sails.js app. Everything was working perfectly until I decided to change from less to scss. I have added scss and can run the app locally, but when I push to the server (and look in the logs) I get the following error:

```
Aborted due to warnings.
Running "sass:dev" (sass) task
Warning:
You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to work.
More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass
```

When I ssh into my DO droplet and run 'sass -v' I get 'Sass 3.4.20 (Selective Steve)' as a response, telling me sass is installed.

I also have '    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.9.2",' in my package.json file.

Not sure where to turn here as dokku is running the same commands on the server as I am on my laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I deleted the droplet. Then setup a new droplet with ubuntu 14.04 x64 and installed dokku-alt, I then installed sass using 'apt-get gem install sass' and it worked.

i am not sure if there was a conflict ob the droplet or ifit was dokku-alt that fixed the issue.